# documentation for a package in php?

Tags: php, phpdoc

so in a folder PayPal i've got multiple classes for using their API.

i want to make a documentation for how to use all the classes in a sequential way. so here is my questions:

1. how do i create a package for them? cause above each class i used phpdoc tag @package PayPal. is a package in php just a folder?
2. where do i put documentation for the package? there are best practices for this? a file in the folder named ...?
3. how to put class- or package-specific examples, eg. step 1 bla bla, step 2 bla bla?
   thanks!

Comment: *(reference)* http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/

Comment: @gordon. seems that they are putting classes in one file. so the file is the package? but is that really a good best practice? cause i was taught one file one class. would be not that good if we mixed them up. maybe its a huge package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the same package annotations for multiple classes in separate files. PHP Documentor will collect them and when creating the API Docs, group files with the same package annotation.

For instance http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate.php

```
/**
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Validate
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2010 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Zend_Validate implements Zend_Validate_Interface
```

and http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/Alnum.php

```
/**
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Validate
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2010 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Zend_Validate_Alnum extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
```

Both are separate files, but belong to the Zend_Validate package. Thus, on http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/ you can find them grouped in the same package.

You can also have subpackages to group additional classes below a normal package. For instance http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/Sitemap/Lastmod.php

```
/**
 * Validates whether a given value is valid as a sitemap <lastmod> value
 *
 * @link       http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php Sitemaps XML format
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Validate
 * @subpackage Sitemap
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2010 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Zend_Validate_Sitemap_Lastmod extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
```

See the above linked API docs to see how it shows when generated.

You do not document package annotations. The annotation is just used to logically group class or files that conceptuially belong to together. If you want to have a package description, write it either into the most appropriate file of the package or create a separate file and give it the same annotation as the other files/classes in that package have.

For examples of usage to packages, you the example annotation to link files which contains examples or simply write them inline with code tags in the DocBlocks. If you are using a separate file to document your packages, you could insert them there.

```
/**
 * MyLib
 *
 * Files under the MyLib package do foo and bar. They are baz.
 * 
 * Usage Examples of MyLib classes
 * <code>
 * $foo = new Foo;
 * $foo->doSomething()
 * </code>
 *
 * @package MyLib
 *
 * @example /some/path/to/an/example/file 
 */
```

Comment: +2 for the excellent documentation (the other one is invisible) :) i just have one problem with navigating the api documentation you linked me. so i choose "Zend_Validate" in the list above to the right "Packages". Then it show on the left. It's here i get confused. I click class and i can see all the classes. But where are the subpackages? It should be a subpackage named "Sitemap" right? And aren´t packages grouped into categories? Where can i find these? I just dont get the hierarchical structure.

Comment: @ajsie It's right below the regular "Classes" node. To my knowledge category is not visible.